# Flutter The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am running my app and getting the error:

"NoSuchMethodError: The Method '[ ]' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling: ."

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../model/Lesson.dart';


class MobileModeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MobileModeScreenState createState() => _MobileModeScreenState();
}


class _MobileModeScreenState extends State<MobileModeScreen> {

  List<Lesson> _lesson;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {
      getLessonFromJSON(context);
    });
    print("lessonDescription: ${_lesson[0].lessonTitle}");
  }

  Future<List<Lesson>> getLessonFromJSON(BuildContext context) async {
    String jsonString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/lessons/lessons.json");

    return await Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {
      List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonString);
      List<Lesson> lesson = data.map( (f) => Lesson.fromJSON(f) ).toList();
      _lesson = lesson;
      print("lessonDescription: ${_lesson[0].lessonTitle}");
      return _lesson;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
              border: Border.all(
                color: Color(0xffF5ED02),
                width: 3,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            ),
            child: Text("lessonDescription: ${_lesson[0].lessonTitle}",
              style: TextStyle(
                //fontFamily: "Uthmani",
                color: Color(0xff225587),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff7F3F96),
        ),

        body: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 15, 5, 5),
          children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffF0E4F2),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not getting the error when I try to access the value from the `getLessonFromJSON` function, but outside of the function, it's not working at all.

The error I get:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///home/hmalabeh/AndroidStudioProjects/Flutter/Bounyan/boynyan_final/lib/main.dart:12:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _MobileModeScreenState.initState (package:boynyanfinal/screens/mobile_mode_screen.dart:26:40)
#2      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:58)
#3      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#4      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
...
```

Can someone help please.

**Update:**
I want to be able to use what I get from the function `getLessonFromJSON` in the `build` method like I'm using in the `Text` filed in the `AppBar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the `setState()` inside the `getLessonFromJSON` and I've added a loader in the places I use values from _lesson as @Sami suggested.

`_lesson` doesn't need to ve initialized.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLessonFromJSON(context);
  }

  Future<List<Lesson>> getLessonFromJSON(BuildContext context) async {
    String jsonString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/lessons/lessons.json");

    try{
      return await Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {
        List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonString);
        List<Lesson> lesson = data.map( (f) => Lesson.fromJSON(f) ).toList();
        setState(() {
          _lesson = List.from(lesson);
        });
        print("[getLessonFromJSON] lessonDescription: ${lesson[0].lessonTitle}");
        return lesson;
      });
    } catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

The loader

```
_lessonTitle = _lesson == null ? 'Loading...' : _lesson[0].lessonTitle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the get data to a different function and await the response:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  load();
}

void load() async {
  setState(() {
    await getLessonFromJSON(context);
  });
}
```

Also place a loader anywhere you're using `_lesson`, example in your Appbar:

```
var text = _lesson == null ? 'Loading...' : 'lessonDescription: ${_lesson[0].lessonTitle}';
Text(text,
  style: TextStyle(
  //fontFamily: "Uthmani",
    color: Color(0xff225587),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Sorry, my description was not clear enough, I've updated the description. what I want to do is to be able to use what I get from the function `getLessonFromJSON` in the `build` method like I'm using in the `Text` filed in the `AppBar`, I've tried what you suggested it didn't help.

Comment: And to avoid crashes before the data loads, you need to add some kind of loader for your screen.

Answer (score 0):

`_lesson` is null because its value is assigned only when `Future.delayed` is resolved.

To solve it, either move `print("lessonDescription: ${_lesson[0].lessonTitle}");` inside `Future` handler (after `getLessonFromJSON(context);`) or just remove that line at all because as far as I can suppose, it's needed only for debugging purposes.

This should work:

```dart
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {
      getLessonFromJSON(context);
      print("lessonDescription: ${_lesson[0].lessonTitle}");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, my description was not clear enough, I've updated the description. what I want to do is to be able to use what I get from the function `getLessonFromJSON` in the `build` method like I'm using in the `Text` filed in the AppBar, yes, I'm using it for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize '_lesson' with an empty list
``` List _lesson = [];````
And then add item to this list in `initState` by using `_lesson.add(item)` and called `setState` to update the state of app. 
This will work but you should FutureBuilder for async operations and use provider or bloc for better State management

Comment: The returned data is of type `List<Lesson>`,  so it won't work to add it using `_lesson.add(item)` since the `item` I'm returning is of type `List<Lesson>` not `Lesson`

Comment: You can use addAll method to a list when all map stuff is done.

Comment: This is not a best practice to do it you should use a FutureBuilder for this give async function to FutureBuilder as a future and returns widget based on the data received from that future and don't forget to do error handling If you don't know how to do it with FutureBuilder then let me know i will do it for you